# Django-sphinx How to get a list of keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, sphinx

If I type in the search for "Home", the answer I get the same word "Homes", etc.
I need to highlight the words on the client, as a result of the search. How to get a list of keywords based on the morphology of the client?

Answer (score 0):

You cant get a list of works as such. Morphology processing to produce a stem is a one way process.

But Sphinx does include a BuildExceprts function! This understands morphology settings and will highlight the relevent matching words.